# CS50 2024 Speller memory leak

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently taking CS50 and working on the Speller questions. I am able to get the code to work but the program fails the valgrind test on check50.

Valgrind tells me the leak of 56bytes is at line 86 where I declared a malloc to store the words as the program scans through the dictionary.

I tried doing a fclose at the end of the while loop but it messes up the code.

```
==75771== HEAP SUMMARY:
==75771==     in use at exit: 7,703,248 bytes in 137,558 blocks
==75771==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 5,538 frees, 8,023,256 bytes allocated
==75771== 
==75771== 7,703,248 bytes in 137,558 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==75771==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==75771==    by 0x109A93: load (dictionary.c:86)
==75771==    by 0x1092DB: main (speller.c:40)
==75771== 
==75771== LEAK SUMMARY:
==75771==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==75771==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==75771==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==75771==    still reachable: 7,703,248 bytes in 137,558 blocks
==75771==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==75771== 
==75771== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==75771== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

//Declare variables
int word_count;
unsigned int hash_value;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //Obtain hash value of word
    hash_value = hash(word);

    //Declare cursor variable
    node *cursor = table[hash_value];

    while (cursor != 0)
    {
        //Return true if match found
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //Move cursor to next node if no match found
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    //Return false if no match after traversing thus misspelt word
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    long sum = 0;
    int hash;

    //Division hash
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(word); i++)
    {
        sum += tolower(word[i]);
    }
    hash = sum % N;

    return hash;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //Open dictionary using fopen r
    FILE *source = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (source == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file %s\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    //Declare word variable to store word while scanning
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    //Loop to scan for word until fscanf returns EOF
    while (fscanf(source, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        //Allocate memory for word node
        node *word_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (word_node == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Copy word from source into node
        strcpy(word_node->word, word);

        //Obtain hash value for word
        hash_value = hash(word);

        //Insert word into respective hash table
        word_node->next = table[hash_value];
        table[hash_value] = word_node;

        word_count++;
    }

    //Close file
    fclose(source);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (word_count > 0)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    //Loop through buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //point cursor to first table
        node *cursor = table[i];

        //move cursor until it reaches the end
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            //create unloader for current cursor position
            node *unloader = cursor;

            //move cursor to next node
            cursor = cursor->next;

            //free memory from current node using unloader
            free(unloader);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where is the main function? Read about this: [mcve]

Comment: OT: look closely at the `size` function. It is overly complicated. I let you find out why.

Comment: @Heleth The function check is not used in the presented code. It seems that memory leaks occur when at first you allocate memory and only then call the function check.

Comment: The algorithm in the unload function is wrong. You stop at the first bucket that is NULL which is obviously wrong. You need to go through all buckets. But worse, the overall approach is wrong anyway, you should not visit the buckets but you should visit the nodes of your linked list. Imagine what happens if you have more word in your list than the hash table size?

Comment: But anyway, there are more problems. The handling of the linked list is incomplete. You don't know why? Then try to write a function that displays all loaded words and you'll find out.

Comment: For size, I guess I could just return the word_count without the if-else since if there are no words counted, 0 will be returned anyways.  As for the unload function, just like what you said, the return true came in too early thus ended the loop before the memory was freed. Shifted it to the end solved the problem.